# Dotnet 6 Trigger Webjob doesn't run directly after deployment

Tags: .net-core, azure-web-app-service, azure-webjobs

I have a Webapp hosting in Azure. Now I created a Triggerd webjob for it. I could deploy it successfully, but after each deployment the status is 'ready' and it will not start to work until I run the WbJobs manually from App Service in Azure.

There is anohter small problem that is nice to have to be fixed. The Schedule is there and after I manually run the TimerJob it will work in correct time interval but in Azure in the App Service in WebJobs section the schedule will not be shown.

any idea?

Goal is that after deployment the Triggered timer job begin its work without to run it manually from the Azure.

Comment: Can you share the cron expression please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem and fixed it.

But what was the problem? I wanted to add a Webjobs of type trigger in my solution and then deploy it with a YAML file into the Azure in a App Service.
Under this link I found the way to write a Triggerd Webjob:
https://thechimpbrain.com/time-triggered-azure-webjob/

In this link the person creates a console application for .net core and in the program file he/she create a hostbuider and this host will run constantly and a function which has the TimerTrigger will call the function in certain time.

But this is not what I want, because if you have an app service, there is already a host running continuously. you should only define the trigger time.

That means you don't need anything form this link. All you do is create a console app and write your code. You should only add a `settings.job` file in your project. There you should define your schedule like this:

```json
{
  "schedule": "0 0 1 * * *"
}
```

In this example it will run every day.

Then you should deploy your project in to the correct place which is in my case `App_Data/jobs/triggered/{YourJobName}`

In your YAML you will have two steps, CI and CD.

In your CI:

```
      - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
        displayName: 'Build Webjob Montly'
        inputs:
          command: 'build'
          projects: 'xxx/xxx/xxx.csproj'
          arguments: '--configuration $(BuildConfiguration)'

      - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
        displayName: 'publish Webjob Montly'
        inputs:
          command: 'publish'
          publishWebProjects: false
          projects: 'xxx/xxx/xxx.csproj'
          arguments: '--output $(Build.BinariesDirectory)/publish_Webjob/App_Data/jobs/triggered/WebjobMontly'
          zipAfterPublish: false
          modifyOutputPath: false

      - task: ArchiveFiles@2
        displayName: 'Zip Webjobs'
        inputs:
          rootFolderOrFile: '$(Build.BinariesDirectory)/publish_Webjob'
          includeRootFolder: false
          archiveType: 'zip'
          archiveFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/Webjobs.zip'
          replaceExistingArchive: true

      - task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
        displayName: Publish drop Artifact
        inputs:
          targetPath: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
          artifact: 'drop'
          publishLocation: 'pipeline'
```

and in your CD:

```
            - task: AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4
              displayName: 'Deploy Webjobs'
              inputs:
                ConnectionType: 'AzureRM'
                azureSubscription: 'xxx'
                appType: 'webApp'
                WebAppName: 'xxx'
                deployToSlotOrASE: true
                ResourceGroupName: 'xxx'
                SlotName: 'Test'
                packageForLinux: '$(pipeline.workspace)/drop/Webjobs.zip'
                JSONFiles: '**/appsettings.json'
```

and that's it.

Answer (score 0):

> Goal is that after deployment the Triggered timer job begin its work without to run it manually from the Azure.

Check the below steps to run the Triggered timer job run automatically.

- Create a Console Application in `Visual Studio`.

[image]

- Build and run the Application locally.
- Zip the `.exe` file in the application `bin/net6.0`  folder.

[image]

- In Azure Portal, Create an  App Service with Runtime stack `.NET6` .

[image]

- In `App Service` => `WebJobs`, add a new Type `Triggered` - `Scheduled` `WebJob`.

[image]

- With the `CRON expression`  which I have given `0 */2 * * * *`, the webjob will start after 2 minutes. And will run after every 2 minutes.

Check the [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/webjobs-dotnet-deploy-vs#scheduling-a-triggered-webjob) for CRON expressions.

***Initial WebJob***

[image]

***After 2 min***

[image]

- We can check the `WebJob` status, under `Logs`.
- Select the `WebJob` and click on `Logs`.

[image]

Click on the Available Job Name.

[image]

- You can see for every 2 minutes the Web Job is getting triggered and running.

[image]

- For testing the job, I have scheduled it to run within few minutes.

Check your CRON expression once.Try with the less timing and cross check.

Comment: tnx for your replay, but I wanted to add webjob through yaml file and not directly in App service